# How to insert a new node in a singly linked list without using a temporary node?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, singly-linked-list

I just started to learn Data Structures and have been trying to implement a simple **singly linked list** in C going step by step. I have been following an online tutorial and while showing how to insert a node to the beginning of the list, it used double asterisks in the function parameters which I couldn't understand and the tutorial didn't explain in detail.

I then worked around this and implemented the function without double pointers (by using a temp node), but I would love to understand and learn how the implementation I saw worked and how I implement it myself.

I taught myself about pointers fairly recently so I cannot say that I'm comfortable with them. Actually that's one of the reasons for why I have started learning Data Structures, to practice them more. I normally understand how *dereferencing* a pointer works, but in this context I am not sure how and with what purpose it's been used in the function header.

I would be so grateful if you could explain the way the function below works.

Here is the function that I couldn't quite get. [(source)](http://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists)

```
void push(node_t ** head, int val) {
    node_t * new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}
```

And here is my implementation:

```
/*
// Singly Linked List Implementation
// 2018/01/10
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
        int val;
        struct node *next;
    } node_t;

void addNodeBegin (node_t *head, int val);
void addNodeEnd (node_t *head, int val);
void printLinkedList();
void freeList(struct node* head);

int main(void) {

    node_t *head = NULL;
    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    if (head == NULL) { return 1; }

    head->val = 1;
    head->next = NULL;

    head->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    head->next->val = 2;
    head->next->next = NULL;

    addNodeEnd(head, 5);
    addNodeBegin(head, 10);
    printLinkedList(head);

    freeList(head);

}

// Insert a node to the beginning of the linked list
void addNodeBegin (node_t *head, int val) {
    node_t *newNode = NULL;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->val = val;

    newNode->next = head->next;
    head->next = newNode;

    node_t *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    tmp->val = head->val;
    head->val = newNode->val;
    head->next->val = tmp->val;

    free(tmp);

}

// Insert a node to the end of the linked list
void addNodeEnd (node_t *head, int val) {
    node_t *current = head;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }

    current->next = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    current->next->val = val;
    current->next->next = NULL;

}

// Print the linked list
void printLinkedList(node_t *head) {
    node_t *current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->val);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

// Remove the list (and free the occupied memory)
void freeList(struct node* head) {
   struct node* tmp;

   while (head != NULL) {
       tmp = head;
       head = head->next;
       free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: You basically ask for a tutorial on pointers. StackOverflow is not the place for that. Look for tutorials via your favorite search engine. Select the one which, too you personally, is written in the most easily understandable way. Work through it. Very important: Take a piece of paper and a pen. Represent values of variables as number/strings inside rectangle. Represent values of pointers as rectangles from which arrows point to other rectangles. Especially with pointers pointing to pointers. Act like being the computer and execute the programs.

Comment: In "C" language, there's at least two common reasons to use pointers : when you allocate memory and when a function modify the value of a parameter. In the `push` function you have these both reasons : `head` points to some allocated memory and the function modify the `head` value. That is why it uses a double pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the simplest way of not doing something is not to do it.

Tracing what the values of things are through your implementation:

```
// Insert a node to the beginning of the linked list
void addNodeBegin (node_t *head, int val) { // assume head = [val1, ...]
    node_t *newNode = NULL;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    newNode->val = val;                     // newNode=[val, null]

    newNode->next = head->next;             // newNode=[val, ...]
    head->next = newNode;                   // head = [val1, [val, ...]]

    node_t *tmp = NULL;
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    tmp->val = head->val;                   // tmp = [val1, undefined]
    head->val = newNode->val;               // head = [val, [val, ...]]
    head->next->val = tmp->val;             // head = [val, [val1, ...]]

    free(tmp);

}
```

Firstly, the only thing temp is doing is storing a copy of head->val, so you could store the value directly instead by setting newNode->val before overwriting head->val:

```
// Insert a node to the beginning of the linked list
void addNodeBegin (node_t *head, int val) { // assume head = [val1, ...]
    node_t *newNode = malloc(sizeof(node_t)); // no need to set to NULL first
    newNode->val = head->val;               // newNode=[val1, undefined]
    newNode->next = head->next;             // newNode=[val1, ...]
    head->next = newNode;                   // head = [val1, [val1, ...]]
    head->val = val;                        // head = [val, [val1, ...]]
}
```

Secondly, this is doing something different to adding a node at the beginning of a list. It is inserting a node after the beginning, then swapping the values between the first and second nodes. This will matter as very commonly singly linked lists have multiple heads, either for performance reasons or to implement specific algorithms, so operations shouldn't change the tail of the list when they prepend to it.
It also means you have to have two different operations - appending to an empty list (NULL) and appending to a non-empty list.

The example implementation of push() takes a pointer to the pointer to the head of the list, creates a new node and mutates that pointer to point to the new node. This seems harder to use than necessary, as it requires taking the address of the pointer to the head.

```
node_t* head = NULL;

push ( &head, 1 );
push ( &head, 2 );
push ( &head, 3 );
push ( &head, 4 );

node_t* head2 = head;

push ( &head2, 5 );
```

Personally I'd just return the pointer to the new node:

```
node_t* cons (int val, node_t* next) {
    node_t * new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

    new_node->val = val;
    new_node->next = next;

    return new_node;
}

node_t* head = cons(4, cons(3, cons(2, cons(1, NULL))));
node_t* head2 = cons(5, head);
```

'Cons' is short for construct, a traditional name for the construction of singly linked lists in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

Think on the double asterisk as a double pointer or a reference to a pointer.... the problem basically is that, in C, you cannot pass a function a variable parameter (or a parameter by reference), and so, the only way to do it is by explicitly passing the address of the pointer you want to modify.  That's the reason of the second asterisk, to make the modification made to the referenced pointer available to the application.  Both levels of reference have different meanings... you cannot pass a variable to be updated to a function as parameter, but you can pass its address.  Passing a double pointer makes this possible and you can update the pointer with something like:

```
*ptr_reference = &node_to_be_referenced;
```

When you call the function, you pass it a reference to the pointer to be modified, something like:

```
function_to_be_called(&pointer_to_first_node, node_to_be_inserted);
```

or, if you want to pass a middle pointer:

```
function_to_be_called(&previous_node_of_inserted->next, node_to_be_inserted);
```

(see how is the address of the pointer what is used to reference the pointer to be modified)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understood your question, so:

In the push function you actually replace the original node pointer in the memory.
E.g if you have the following list:
1->2->3->5, and you have pointer to 1, after the push function with val 6, the list will contains: 6->1->2->3->5. but your head node will point to 6 (actual address of the pointer will be changed. The head pointer will point to another place in the memory).

In the second option, you don't change the pointer of the head. You just change the values of the struct (next actually). With the previous example, after the insert the head pointer will still point to the same location in the memory.